# Why am I receiving "Unknown column 'xyz'" with WHERE clause on View SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, view, where-clause

MySQL database (community) version: 5.6.27, Windows 7 Pro x64

I've just created this View:

```
DELIMITER $$

ALTER ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`admin`@`%` SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `vw_qb_assembly_component_info` AS (
SELECT
  `qb_assembly_components`.`assembly_item_id`   AS `assemblyId`,
  `ai`.`name`                                   AS `assemblyName`,
  `qb_assembly_components`.`component_quantity` AS `componentQuantity`,
  `qb_assembly_components`.`component_item_id`  AS `item_id`,
  `ci`.`name`                                   AS `name`,
  `ci`.`item_number_type`                       AS `item_number_type`,
  `ci`.`type`                                   AS `type`

FROM ((`qb_assembly_components`
    JOIN `qb_items` `ai`
      ON ((`ai`.`item_id` = `qb_assembly_components`.`assembly_item_id`)))
   JOIN `qb_items` `ci`
     ON ((`ci`.`item_id` = `qb_assembly_components`.`component_item_id`))))$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I am attempting to query the view for rows with a certain `qb_assembly_components`.`assembly_item_id` value. I've tried several variations of defining the column in the WHERE clause but always receive error:

> Unknown column 'xyz' in 'where clause'

The following are the versions I've tried:

```
WHERE `qb_assembly_components`.`assemblyId` = 'RR-0T056'
WHERE `qb_assembly_components`.`assembly_item_id` = 'RR-0T056'
WHERE `assemblyId` = 'RR-0T056'
```

I'm stumped. I've googled a bit and found a few results that seem to suggest using the alias is the way to go (my last example in the above 3 examples) but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are select from   `VIEW`vw_qb_assembly_component_info``

then the where clause should refer to the view name (and not to the orginal table name)

```
WHERE `vw_qb_assembly_component_info`.`assemblyId` = 'RR-0T056'
```